# What does TFS 2018 use SharePoint for?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

At work, I've been put into the role of TFS administrator, as the real TFS admin is leaving our organization in two weeks. We're currently using TFS 2015. I'm trying to upgrade us to TFS 2018, hopefully before the current admin leaves.

To that end, I've been reading various resources on TFS migration from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018. One resource I came across is this one [Migration from TFS 2015 to 2018](https://www.aspiresys.com/articles/Migration-from-TFS-2015-to-2018.pdf). This document spoke about integration between TFS 2018 and SharePoint. I had thought that integration died, after TFS 2015. Specifically, up to TFS 2015, TFS had what they called "TFS Project rooms". Sort of like a simple bulletin board type system. But Microsoft decided to break that connection, so I was lead to believe, after TFS 2015.

So, I'm wondering, since the linked to PDF speaks of integration between TFS 2018 and SharePoint, what is that about? Especially if TFS team rooms have gone away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this doc about [TFS 2018 and SharePoint integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2018-relnotes#--discontinuing-tfs-extension-for-sharepoint):

> TFS 2018 and later versions no longer support integration with SharePoint.

The SharePoint integration supports the TFS 2017 and earlier versions. In  TFS 2017 and earlier versions, in addition to the team room function, this integration also has other functions.

For more detailed information about sharepoint integration , you could refer [this Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/the-future-of-our-tfs-sharepoint-integration/).

Since you are upgrading the TFS 2015 to TFS 2018, if you have configured the SharePoint integration in TFS 2015, you need to [disable the SharePoint integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/report/sharepoint-dashboards/deprecation/disable-tfs-sharepoint-integration-after-tfs-2018-upgrade?view=azure-devops) after upgrade.

In addition, in TFS 2018, we start to use [Microsoft teams](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.vss-services-teams) or slack for monitoring and communication.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Think this MS-Post might give you the answers: [The future of TFS/Sharpoint Integration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/the-future-of-our-tfs-sharepoint-integration/)